# Selenium IEDriverServer unable to configure protected mode due to security policy

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-7, selenium-webdriver, protected-mode, security-policy

The [IEDriverServer Wiki page](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver) has the following listed as a requirement:

> On IE 7 or higher on Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must set the
>   Protected Mode settings for each zone to be the same value. The value
>   can be on or off, as long as it is the same for every zone.

Unfortunately, where I work, corporate security policy has the protected mode setting locked down, so I'm unable to make changes to the setting.

Is there a way to work around this issue and get the IEDriverServer working?  Or is Selenium just not an option for corporate environments that run IE 7+ on Windows 7 where the users are prevented from changing the Protected Mode settings?

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: Which version of selenium are you on?

Comment: am also facing the same issue in corp environments :(

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.

I solved it by direct edit to registry.

Although the following is an example of Java, it can be similarly used in another language. 
I call this method before IEDriver instance creation.

If you want to disable it, please set the 3 instead of 0.

```
private void enableIEProtectModeOfAllZones() {

    final String[] ZONES = {
        "\"HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\Zones\\1\""
        , "\"HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\Zones\\2\""
        , "\"HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\Zones\\3\""
        , "\"HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\Zones\\4\""
    };
    for (String zone : ZONES) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "reg", "add",
                zone, "/v", "2500", "/t", "REG_DWORD", "/d", "0", "/f");
        try {
            pb.start();
        } catch (IOException ioe) { ioe.printStackTrace(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just for anyone else who winds up here. Don't forget to reboot after you've modified the registry.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are using Selenium Webdriver.
Please add the following: `capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true`) to your driver set up.

Comment: This did not work for me with 2.24.1, however it had worked for me in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create IE Driver instance with parameters, I'm assuming you are using C#

```
InternetExplorerOptions opts = new InternetExplorerOptions();
opts.IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true;

IWebDriver wDriver =  new InternetExplorerDriver(opts);
```

That will solve your issue